# Why is my left-parenthesis mapping to "KP Page Up"?

Tags: xubuntu, keyboard, shortcut-keys

I recently switched from Ubuntu to Xubuntu, and the most persistent of the little glitches has been a weird keyboard mapping that I don't know how to fix. I'm on an Asus UX21 laptop, and I've been running Ubuntu for several years without encountering this issue.

I can't type a left parentheses. When I press the <kbd>9</kbd> key, it produces a `9`. But when I press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd> to get a left parenthesis, it doesn't work. Generally what happens is that all of the preceding text gets selected. When I use that key combination in the XFCE GUI tool for creating shortcuts (`Settings > Keyboard > Application Shortcuts`), it interprets the combination as <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Page Up</kbd>. Why would my <kbd>9</kbd> key turn into <kbd>KP Page Up</kbd> when I am holding down the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key?

The problem persists both when I'm using, in the Keyboard settings, both "system default" and the "ASUS Laptop" layouts.

Any suggestions about how I can address this? Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: I have no idea why, but after several days of persisting the problem has gone away! Ooookay... (proof!)

Comment: Okay, further update: The problem persists. It only went away because my laptop was plugged into an external keyboard. Interestingly, when so plugged in, even the laptop's own keyboard was working correctly. But then when the external keyboard was disconnected, the problem recurred.